# Why can't the 'this' pointer be used in the constructor initializer list?

Tags: c++

I mean, we can't do:

```
class A {
    int i;
    char c;
public:
    A(int i = 0, char c = ' ') : this->i(i), this->c(c) {}
};
```

Is it because the instance hasn't been created yet or something like that?

Comment: Those names are already unambiguous. `this` is not required.

Comment: I think they are ambiguous as they have the same identifier. Why do you feel otherwise?

Comment: I think I see your point. Won't mind an explanation though just to be safe.

Comment: It's used in the context of initializing a member. The only thing to initialize here is `this->i`, and the only reasonable thing to initialize it with is the parameter `i`. I guess that was good enough for a decision to be made when designing the language that those are the ones used here.

Comment: @Grendan: It's not a question of feeling. It's mandated by the standard.

Comment: you can't as it is standard , use this inside constructor (under braces) not in initialization list.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `this` keyword in the initializer list as anything in the initializer list must be declared within the class. When you do

```
class MyClass
{
    int member;
public:
    MyClass(int member) : member(member) { }
                          ^^^^^ Can only be resolved to a member of MyClass
}
```

`member` in the initializer list is not permitted to refer to anything other than `int member` within the class. Therefore the this keyword is unnecessary and would add additional parsing difficulties if compilers had to support both `member(member)` and `this->member(member)` within initializer list. While giving the impression that it is possible to initialize non-member variables within the initializer list at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at an [overview of the C++ grammar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903594(v=vs.71).aspx), specifically the `mem-initializer-list` section, you see that the initializer list should consist of `identifier(expression)` or `classname(expression)` entries. An `identifier` is defined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903592(v=vs.71).aspx) as string of digits and nondigits (a-z, A-Z, _).

Your `this->identifier(expression)` doesn't match that, so it's not allowed. It's not necessary anyway, because there is no ambiguity here. The `identifier` is always a member variable of the class, so it's clear which `i` is referred to.

```
class A {
    int i;
    char c;
public:
    A(int i = 0, char c = ' ') : i(i), c(c) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `this` like that:

```
class A {
    int i;
    char c;
public:
    A(int i = 0, char c = ' ') : i(i), c(c) {} // syntax makes this good
};
```

That is totally fine and works exactly how you want it to work.

The syntax rules mean that parameters can not appear as the variable being initialized, only its parameter. So the compiler must resolve the variables outside the parens `i()` as the class member and the one inside the parens `(i)` from the parameters *because* they *hide* the member variables due to scoping rules.

```
A(int i = 0): i(i) {}
              ^       - syntax says that i must be a member 

A(int i = 0): i(i) {}
                ^     - syntax says normal scoping rules apply
```

Outside the parens it *must* be a class member but *inside* the parens the scoping rules are like in the constructor body - the parameters hide the member variables.

So it is a perfectly safe pattern to use to name your parameters the same as your data members.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `this` pointer needs to be inside one of the following:

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this):

> It can appear in the following contexts:
>   1) Within the body of any non-static member function, including member
>   initializer list 
>   2) within the declaration of a non-static member
>   function anywhere after the (optional) cv-qualifier sequence,
>   including dynamic exception specification(deprecated), noexcept
>   specification(C++11), and the trailing return type(since C++11)
>  
>   3)
>   within brace-or-equal initializer of a non-static data member (since
>   C++11)

```
class Foo {
    int a[sizeof(*this)]; // error, not inside a member function
};
```

Similarly:

```
class A {
    int i = sizeof(*this); // valid - brace-or-equal initializer
    char c;
public:
    // Error, not inside member function.
    A(int i = 0, char c = ' ') : this->i(i), this->c(c) // invalid
    {}
};
```

When put inside of the body of the constructor, it will work:

```
A(int i = 0, char c = ' ')
{
    this->c = c; // 'this->' required for disambiguation
    this->i = i;
}

A(int i = 0, char c = ' ') : i(sizeof(*this)) // also valid
{}
```

It is often not necessary to use `this->` explicitly.